# Как перенести изображения в формате gif в другой документ

Tags: изображения, google-apps-script, gif

Есть в документе анимированная картинка в формате gif, ее нужно перенести в другой документ. Проблема в том, что не получается сделать это без потери анимации.

Пока знаю только один способ добавления изображения в документ. Примерно так:

```js
var targetBody=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
targetBody.appendImage(image);
```

Получить image пробовал всеми методами, которые есть в классе Body: findElement(elementType), getChild(childIndex), getImages(). Результат один - переносится статичное изображение, анимация не работает.

Пробовал также откреплять изображение не методом copy(), а путем удаления его из родительского элемента. Это помогло с правильным переносом изображений внутри таблицы. Но в случае с gif опять же не действует.

Может ли кто подсказать решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При получении картинки и ее деаттаче копируется оптимизированная копия. Чтобы получить исходную картинку (или оптимизированную под формат, т.к. не все картинки сохраняются в исходном варианте при загрузке), вам необходимо получить исходник файла в виде архива или файла odt.

Я предпочитаю odt, т.к. там внятная разметка. Но если нужны индексы картинок, то лучше zip.

```
var exl = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=zip';
var url = exl + '&id=XXX'; 
var zip = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
```

Далее распаковываете zip

```
 var blobs = Utilities.unzip(zip);
```

В блобах находите картинку, добавляете ее в новый Документ.

Адаптировал пример под [сниппеты](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/dev/snippets/document_copy_inlineimage/document_copy_inlineimage.js)

```
/* exported run, getBlobImageByIndexFromDoc_ */

/**
 * @param {string} from The ID of a Document with the inlineImage
 * @param {number} index The index of the inlineImage. Starts from 1
 */
function getBlobImageByIndexFromDoc_(from, index) {
  var template =
    'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=%s&exportFormat=zip';
  var url = Utilities.formatString(template, from);
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  }).getBlob();
  var patt = new RegExp(
    Utilities.formatString('images\\/image%s\\..{3}', index)
  );
  var blob = Utilities.unzip(file).find(function(b) {
    return patt.test(b.getName());
  });
  return blob;
}

/**
 * Runs the example
 * @ignore
 */
function run() {
  var blob = getBlobImageByIndex(
    '1_IyrjvBAK1c1hNcG0yYP41XFYmO7m_zOTfmwLktaCGY',
    1
  );
  var dest = DocumentApp.openById(
    '1h7_W36wN-9p2Msabj-ZBcHLGQWdX-QtB_YqBpsmrMp0'
  );
  dest.getBody().appendImage(blob);
}
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш метод. Не все у меня получилось, после некоторой пляски с бубном вычислил несколько более короткий способ:    `var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=XXX");      targetBody.appendImage(resp.getBlob());`  все корректно добавилось без всякого архивирования.

Comment: Проблема в том, что это лишь частичное решение задачи. С исходным документом будет работать другой человек и, получается, этот человек должен будет помнить, что ему нужно вставлять в документ не гифку , а  только ссылку на нее, а сам .gif файл загружать на гугл-диск. Это будет очень неудобно.

Comment: Пробовал сохранять гифку на диск через DriveApp.createFile(blob) - увы, на выходе все то же статичное изображение.

Comment: Так у вас получилось или нет? Так бодро начали. Не меняйте коней на переправе, и будет вам радость. То у вас гифка в доке, а тут уже на диске лежмя лежит. Вы определитесь с задачей-то.

Comment: Картинка у меня в доке (смотрите вопрос). И нужно перенести ее в другой док. Я рассматривал, как возможный вариант решения проблемы - сначала как-то сохранить ее на диск, а потом с диска - в другой док. Вторая часть получилась - с вашей помощью. Первая пока нет.

Comment: И все же это тоже не очень удобный способ. Я надеюсь найти решение, чтобы без промежуточного сохранения. Что интересно - если гифку копировать в тот же документ, анимация работает. Хотя код тот же самый, только ссылка не на другой документ а на исходник.

Comment: Мой пример ничего на Диск не сохраняет. Блоб живёт только во время исполнения скрипта.

Comment: Сорри, неправильно понял про "исходник файла". Я решил, что это исходник гифки, загруженный на диск, и подставлял его идентификатор. А надо было идентификатор документа. Как только подставил его, все стало на свои места и заработало, как требовалось. Но, к сожалению, почему-то с именно с тем документом, который нужен и с некоторыми другими метод все-таки не работает.  Прерывает исполнение на `var blobs = Utilities.unzip(zip);` пишет- "недействительный аргумент". И никак не могу понять, чем эти доки отличаются от тех, с которыми код срабатывает. Вроде бы и размеры небольшие и картинок немного..

Comment: Пробовал перед раззиповаванием указывать тип контента: `zip = setContentType("application/zip")`.  Тогда `var blobs = Utilities.unzip(zip)` проходит без ошибок, но в блобах ничего нет. blobs.length равна нулю

Comment: Странно. Можете поделиться проблемным Документом?

Comment: Вот, например: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1X1Qjg7PR77gO-mQ0rjaRVgU1Ky6GPfpInw_IquKZO0A/edit?usp=sharing.  Или вот: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_IyrjvBAK1c1hNcG0yYP41XFYmO7m_zOTfmwLktaCGY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Yurij_Bi, восхищен вашим терпением и упорством. Добавил пример. Ваши файлы для меня работают.

Comment: Всегда к вашим услугам )). Вот вам еще сырья для ваших сниппетов. Во-первых, ваш пример у меня не работает. Ругается на строчку `var blob = Utilities.unzip(file).find(function(b) {`. Пишет "Не удается обнаружить функцию find в объекте Blob,Blob". Но это не принципиально. Главное - во-вторых. Попробуйте вашим способом вытащить первую картинку из вот этого документа: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_IyrjvBAK1c1hNcG0yYP41XFYmO7m_zOTfmwLktaCGY/edit?usp=sharing. Я почти уверен - вылезет не 1-я, а 3-я. (по времени добавления она вторая). Но в blobs она имеет индекс 1 и имя "images/image1.png".

Comment: И такая канитель в большинстве документов. Т.е. индексы картинок в массиве blobs (из вашего первого примера) идут не в том порядке, как в документе. И как тогда найти нужную картинку?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Comment: Спасибо, добавление Array.prototype.find позволило использовать .find(). Но ведь это решение только первой части проблемы, я правильно понял? Главный вопрос,как соотнести порядковые номера картинок в документе с их индексами в blobs[] по-прежнему остается не решенным.

Comment: Я мапаю XML из odt, но выбрать оттуда конкретный пример на получится. Поэтому, вы можете просто читать html, делать ему match, потом брать имя картинки уже по порядковому индексу, и только после этого брать нужный блоб. Сниппет обновил в репе.

Comment: @Yurij_Bi, ну как?

Comment: Да, спасибо, все заработало. Не совсем еще разобрался, как работает ваш последний сниппет, но его применение решило проблему.